# Programmatically add key from X509Certificate2 via PKCS#11 to a key store

Tags: .net, pkcs#11

We have a secure key store which features a PKCS#11 interface. We access keys on it using the [PKCS#11 Interop Library for .NET](https://pkcs11interop.net/). We also need to import keys from certificates. How to import the PrivateKey of an `X509Certificate2` via our PKCS#11 interface into our key store?

```
var key = x509Certificate2.PrivateKey;

var attributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();

// What to do here? How to fill in the key into those attributes?

pkcs11Session.CreateObject(attributes);
```

Comment: What's the concrete question? What attributes you need? Or how you get the actual key from the `AsymmetricAlgorithm` object?

Comment: Both, I guess. I can obtain a "CSP blob" from the AsymmetricAlgorithm object by casting it to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, however, I don't know how to convert the CSP blob into a list of object attributes which make up a key in terms of PKCS#11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is about how to actually extract the private key details from an `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey`, here is an example with a PFX file:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"self-signed.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var rsaPrivateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var parameters = rsaPrivateKey.ExportParameters(true);
```

However, the exact code depends on a few things, namely

- how the certificate is created and whether it actually contains a private key reference (in this case, yes, imported from PFX),
- whether the key is exportable (in this case, yes), and
- the type of private key (in this case, RSA).

I can't help you about how to convert that into the attributes required by your library, though, maybe someone else can chime in here.

Comment: For the actual attributes see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53741823/1400869